# Why does my app not start through Visual Studio Code terminal?

Tags: node.js

When I start the app through cmd.exe, everything is ok, but when started through VSC terminal (powershell or cmd) I get error like on the screenshot below.

[image]

I've already checked NODE_OPTIONS, the app would not run in cmd if the options weren't set correctly.

**EDIT**

Start command: nx run hub:serve

Result of 'console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))' =
10288 (in cmd.exe)

But when I run the command in cmd.exe terminal inside VSC the result is = 4144

Comment: please attach result of "node -e 'console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))'" and your start command.

Answer (score 1):

The command I requested shows the maximum memory that node can use.

Since the values ​​used in cmd and vs are different, the results will also be different.

That means your settings are not recognized by the node.

So what you do is to pass the NODE_OPTIONS so that vs also uses the set value.

I'm not sure you are same in below issue.

https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3004

If that, your package.json maybe like this

```
...
"hub:serve" : "node --max_old_space_size=10288 node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js"
...
```